# Create formula with string as source

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can I create a formula with a separate cell to direct to a specific cell of column in that formula?

For example, I'm now having this formula to compare two column values:

```
=arrayformula(if(I3:I=J3:J;"√";"Check"))
```

I don't constantly want to manually edit the formula if I want to compare other columns, lets say: A to B. It would be ideal to have two cells with where I can type in "A" and "B".

So the formula could look something like this:

```
=arrayformula(if(<cell A1>3:<cell A1>=<cell A2>3:<cell A2>;"√";"Check"))
```

Content in cell A1: A
Content in cell A2: B

Should create the formula:
=arrayformula(if(A3:A=B3:B;"√";"Check"))

Of course this currently doesn't work because A and B are strings.

Comment: there is a script which is able to convert strings into formulae - if you interested in such solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDIRECT`:

```
=arrayformula(if(<cell A1>3:<cell A1>=<cell A2>3:<cell A2>;"√";"Check"))
```

would be

```
=arrayformula(if(INDIRECT(A1&3&":"&A1)=INDIRECT(A2&3&":"&A2);"√";"Check"))
```

However, due to performance issues, It is not recommended to use `INDIRECT`

Comment: Thanks! But I get "√" as a result, though some results should be false ("Check").